# No input after suspend/sleep

Tags: suspend, pulseaudio, input

After my Dell computer goes to sleep, I can move the mouse around fine and it brings the screen back up.  I can't click on anything or type anything.  I don't know much about Linux and it is even harder to diagnose because I can't type a terminal command or anything else.

I have to force shut down and restart if I walk away from my computer for a few minutes.  I reinstalled the OS and that worked for about a week and then it broke again. I only installed a few apps off the Ubuntu software like Audacity and PulseAudio control.

Please help.  This makes my computer very inconvenient to use.

Comment: This is the second Ubuntu forum that I've posted to about this problem with zero responses.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there more information I can give you?

Comment: Ubuntu version you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: 64 bit, Intel Core i7 CPU M 620 @ 2.67 GHz x 4